# ffmpeg maintain aspect ratio on tv that plays fullscreen

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

I have a video with 4:3 aspect ratio (640x480) that my tv insists on playing in full screen, stretching and wrecking the video. Is there a sure fire way to lock the 4:3 aspect ratio as through usb my tv has no way to set it manually.

I have tried already encoding with these commands, which do nothing to help.

```
ffmpeg -i "%a.mp4" -aspect 640:480 -c copy "%a.mp4"
ffmpeg -i "%a.mp4" -vf "scale=640:-1" -c:v libx264 "%a.mp4"
ffmpeg -i "%a.mp4" -vf "scale=640:480" -c:v libx264 "%a.mp4"
ffmpeg -i "%a.mp4" -sar 4:3 -c copy "%a.mp4"
```

Tv is TCL 32D2700

Answer (score 0):

If your TV won't "fit" the frame, you'll have to pad the video so the frame matches the TV display's aspect ratio.

```
ffmpeg -i "%a.mp4" -vf "pad=2*trunc(ih*16/9/2):ih:'(ow-iw)/2':'(oh-ih)/2'" -c:v libx264 "out.mp4"
```

BTW, ffmpeg can't update the input in place, so output file has to be different.